# How can i configure muc in ejabberd.One to One chat working perfect

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I want to know how to setup muc in ejabberd and store the data in mysql.One to one chat working perfect and stores in mysql database.Is there any settings we need to make to enable fro muc and store the data in MYSQL.

```
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local:
    - allow: local
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create:
    - allow: all
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register:
    - allow: all
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network:
```

Thank you

Comment: The configuration you pasted is an unrelated random snippet from the config file and has nothing to do with mod_muc or MySQL database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To configure ejabberd to support Multi-User chat, you need to enable `mod_muc` module. It is described in ejabberd documentation: [mod_muc](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#modmuc).

As you see, the module supports a `db_type` parameter to instruct it to use you configured [MySQL database](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/databases/mysql/) as back end.